# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, how can i fix it?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

my syntax when i ran it, idk it always said syntax error: invalid syntax at line 3, pls help me fix this

```
nterms = int(input("How many terms? "

n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0,


if nterms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")

elif nterms == 1:
  print("sequence upto",nterms,":")
   print(n1)

else
   print("sequence:")
   while count < nterms
       print(n1)
       nth = n1 + n2
       
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
```

Comment: Include the traceback message. That makes it easier to spot the problem.

Comment: `nterms = int(input("How many terms? "`  should be `nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))`.

Comment: There are many more things wrong with this code besides what is complained about here (an error like this can only tell you about one problem at a time). I see at least three more syntax errors, without even trying to figure out what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))

n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0


if nterms <= 0:
    print("Please enter a positive integer")

elif nterms == 1:
    print("sequence upto",nterms,":")
    print(n1)

else:
    print("sequence:")
    while count < nterms:
        print(n1)
        nth = n1 + n2
       
        n1 = n2
        n2 = nth
        count += 1
```

first is the bracket in first line "))"

second count is defined as tuple remove comma  otherwise it will throw error later as tuple plus integer is not supported

add colon after else and while ":"